# How to filter through a PowerShell array and bind the results to a -MemberOf group?

Tags: arrays, powershell, active-directory

I am creating a script that creates a new Active Directory user on the network. I would also like the user to be a member of certain security groups. My problem is, I have an array of groups in the form of strings and would like to filter through the array and assign the groups depending if the string contains a certain phrase.

I have tried `-MemberOf $Groups.contains("Chicken")` but I get the following error:

```bsh
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership : Cannot bind parameter 'MemberOf'.
Cannot convert value "False" to type "Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup".
Error: "Invalid cast from 'System.Boolean' to 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup'.
```

and also `-MemberOf $Groups | Where-Object -eq "Chicken"` and get the following error:

```bsh
Cannot convert the "Chicken" value of type "System.String" to type "System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock".
```

Code:

```
$Groups = "Chicken Developer","Egg Developer","Chicken and Egg Developer"

Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $Username -MemberOf $Groups | Where-Object -eq "Chicken"
```

or

```
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $Username -MemberOf $Groups.Contains("Chicken")
```

Comment: read the help for `where-object`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think from the bottom up.

You have a list of group names:

```
$groups = "Chicken", "Egg", "Chicken and Egg"
```

You want to return only the group names that contain "Chicken":

```
$groups | Where-Object {$_ -like "*Chicken*"}
```

And you want to pass this result to the `-MemberOf` parameter to `Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership` to add the user to those groups:

```
Add-ADPrincipalGroupMembership -Identity $UserName -MemberOf ($Groups | Where-Object {$_ -like "*Chicken*"})
```